# Chrome css fixed positioning of pseudo element not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position, fixed, pseudo-element

I can't figure out why the following css works in Firefox, Safari but not in Chrome. I am trying to create a top fixed navbar which is centered and have a full width black background bar while keeping the contents of the navbar to display within 1200px max-width. I need to achieve this in a Squarespace template where I can only add custom CSS to an existing template and I don't have access to the page code. So I elected the pseudo insertion approach. All is good except Chrome doesn't want to display it correctly. The site link:
https://mango-lanternfish-lzhh.squarespace.com/
Thank you for your assistance in advance.
Attila

```
body, #navigator header#topBar { 
    max-width: 1200px !important; 
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }

#navigator header#topBar { background-color: #000000 !important; }

#navigator header#topBar:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 85px !important;
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: I see a `-webkit-perspective: 1000;` on the `#topBar` element there, once I overwrite that with that `inherit` or `none`, it seems to work. Is that actually needed for anything here?

Comment: Hi 04FS, 
What do you recommend as an overwriting value? If I overwrite that "-webkit-perspective: 1000;" does it affect anything in the page rendering? Thanks,

Comment: I don’t know what exactly that was supposed to achieve in the first place, so … test it, and see what results you get.